# Blazor sanitize MarkupString

Tags: asp.net-core, struct, blazor, html-sanitizing

I'm trying to sanitize content of MarkupString. Actually I created this (based from https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/574be0d22c1678ed5f6db990aec78b4db587b267/src/Components/Components/src/MarkupString.cs)

```
public struct MarkupStringSanitized
{
    public MarkupStringSanitized(string value)
    {
        Value = value.Sanitize();
    }

    public string Value { get; }

    public static explicit operator MarkupStringSanitized(string value) => new MarkupStringSanitized(value);

    public override string ToString() => Value ?? string.Empty;
}
```

But render output isn't raw html. How should I implement MarkupStringSanitized to use

```
@((MarkupStringSanitized)"Sanitize this content")
```

Comment: _“But render output isn't raw html”_ – What do you mean with that?

Comment: I mean that the text is rendered as pure text and is not recognized as html https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAj3y.png

Comment: Whats the problem with: `Markdown.ToHtml(Text, pipeline)`?

Comment: Pls ignore my comment... This is from an external [library](https://jonhilton.net/blazor-markdown-editor/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Couple of suggestions (Not necessarily for OP, but for anyone else looking to solve the problem):

- You didn't provide the code that does the actual sanitization, so I'm going to state the (hopefully) obvious best practice and if you're following it, great. **Do not use Regular Expressions (Regex) to parse HTML**
- Also, the `Sanitize()` method should follow the pattern of `immutability`  in this case
- I would suggest the following library [`Gans.XSS.HtmlSanitizer`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlSanitizer/) which is an active library and updated regularly.

### The problem

Razor View Engine can doesn't know how to render a `MarkupStringSanitized`. Just because you duck typed a sanitized version of the same `struct` doesn't mean it can render it. To get this to render, you'll need to cast it to something it does know, `MarkupString`

Here's what happens when I used your `HtmlSanitizedMarkup` directly with no modifications.

```cs
@((MarkupStringSanitized)Content)
```

[image]

### Working Example #1

Here's an example using my Markdown -> Html playground (fully tested and working):

[image]

MarkupStringSanitized.cs

```cs
public struct MarkupStringSanitized
{
    public MarkupStringSanitized(string value)
    {
        Value = Sanitize(value);
    }

    public string Value { get; }

    public static explicit operator MarkupStringSanitized(string value) => new MarkupStringSanitized(value);

    public static explicit operator MarkupString(MarkupStringSanitized value) => new MarkupString(value.Value);

    public override string ToString() => Value ?? string.Empty;

    private static string Sanitize(string value)  {
        var sanitizer = new HtmlSanitizer();
        return sanitizer.Sanitize(value);
    }
}
```

MarkupStringSanitizedComponent.razor

```cs
@if (Content == null)
{
    <span>Loading...</span>
}
else
{
    @((MarkupString)(MarkupStringSanitized)Content)
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

That extra conversion though is ugly IMO. (maybe someone smarter than me can clean that up?)

### Working example #2

Here I tried extending the `MarkupString` with an extension method.  It looks a little better, but only a *little*.

MarkupStringExtensions.cs

```cs
public static class MarkupStringExtensions
{
    public static MarkupString Sanitize(this MarkupString markupString)
    {
        return new MarkupString(SanitizeInput(markupString.Value));
    }

    private static string SanitizeInput(string value)
    {
        var sanitizer = new HtmlSanitizer();
        return sanitizer.Sanitize(value);
    }
}
```

MarkupStringSanitizedComponent.razor

```cs
@if (Content == null)
{
    <span>Loading...</span>
}
else
{
    @(((MarkupString)Content).Sanitize())
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Right, I forgot to describe the sanitize method, but it is the same as yours that use gans antixss. I like both solutions, i will use the working example #2. Thank you

Comment: I have another solution incoming, it's more idiomatic of Blazor to put this in a component. I'll update the answer when it's complete so check back!

Comment: This is actually great, thank you very much Adam