# MarkupString does not work as expected with String.Format in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

I am trying to use to apply string format to a string coming from a resource file.

```
<p class="note">@((MarkupString)(String.Format(Localizer["Test"], 2)))</p>
```

But this is how it is displayed in the browser:

```
You have done <span class="text-primary text-bold"> 2 </span> tests.
```

What should I do for it to take the proper styling?

I've tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60787929/13419834) but it says:

```
The type or namespace name 'HtmlSanitizer' could not be found
```

I am using Blazor server with .NET6

EDIT:
I have a file called App.resx

```
<data name="Test" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>
      You have done 
      &amp;lt;span class="text-primary text-bold"&amp;gt; 
        {0}
      &amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;
      tests.
    </value>   
</data>
```

Comment: What is the expected output? What does `Localizer["Test"]` return?

Comment: ```@inject IStringLocalizer<App> Localizer```. It checks the culture/language set.

Comment: No, I mean what is the string value that `Localizer["Test"]` returns? What is the string value for `Test` key in your resx?

Comment: It holds the value: ```You have done &lt;span class="text-primary text-bold"&gt; {0} &lt;/span&gt; tests```

Comment: Note that `IStringLocalizer` already incorporates formatting capability, so you can use `@((MarkupString)(string)Localizer["Test", 2])` or `@(new MarkupString(Localizer["Test", 2]))`.  Ensure that you only pass safe parameters, though, otherwise you're vulnerable to HTML injection attacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have double encoded the resource string, change it to `You have done &lt;span class="text-primary text-bold"&gt; {0} &lt;/span&gt; tests`:

```xml
<data name="Test" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>You have done &lt;span class="text-primary text-bold"&gt; {0} &lt;/span&gt; tests</value>
</data>
```

So `Localizer["Test"]` returns `You have done <span class="text-primary text-bold"> {0} </span> tests`.

Note that if you are using resource editor you can just add the string as is and it will encode it correctly so it can be stored in the xml.

Comment: Exactly. `&amp;lt;` should be `&lt;`.  Perhaps you can just code `<span>` inside the resx value, I would try that